# odoo 9 performance on ChromeOS

Tags: performance, odoo-9, google-chrome-os

We are noticing a strong downfall in ODOO performance of the users that use ChromeOS, either using ChromeBook or ChromeBoxes (with different configurations...also very fast ones). After the startup of the machine all seems fine but after a while (depending on your activity) we notice a strong downfall in Performance. It is like the machine is not responding at all and after a few seconds (sometimes up to 30 seconds) it continues with opening the screen and seems to be very quick again. Restarting the browser and clearing the cache gives some relieve but the issue keeps coming back. Strange thing is that on our older windows machines (running Chrome Browser) we do not see this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about, or solvable by, programming.

Comment: Hello Spacedman....I understand your point, however, this is also what the infrastructure people are telling me...they say it is not something which can be solved on their end...it is the application (ODOO) which is causing this slow performance.

Comment: That doesn't matter - this isn't the right forum to ask fairly vague questions about an application's performance.  If there's an odoo-9 dedicated support forum or other community help, I'd take it there.